# Oracle virtual box share folders when executing oracle command

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm using Oracle Developer Days virtual box, which is a Linux distribution by Oracle for development environments ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html)). Not sure what distribution is it, but in case it was relevant:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: EnterpriseEnterpriseServer
Description:    Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Carthage)
Release:        5.5
Codename:       Carthage
```

Host is Mac OS, although that certainly shouldn't relevant for the problem.

I've setup a shared directory between the host and the vm, and as pointed out [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52667/file-permission-issues-with-shared-folders-under-virtual-box-ubuntu-guest-wind) I've added `oracle` Linux user to the group `vboxsf` (upvoted the answer of course). I'm using the shared directory in order to load files into the database using Oracle's external tables. I've got quite a few files to load repetitively and I really need to automate the process and to control it from the host.

The remaining problem is that Oracle, when loading the file, needs to write a new file in the same shared folder, basically including a log and a list of bad registers that could not be loaded. I also would need to check these log files from the host. The problem: Oracle can't write the file. It gives the following error:

```
ORA-29913: error al ejecutar la llamada de ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN
ORA-29400: error de cartucho de datos
error opening file ﻿/media/sf_sisifo01/restapi1/TWEET_LOAD_3205.log
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.
```

(Sorry about the mixture of languages, the vm is in English but I installed SQL Developer in Spanish. Anyway, it is quite understandable).

It cannot write to the shared directory, which is mounted at `/media/sf_sisifo01`. If I try to write to the same directory with `oracle` Linux user, there is no problem, I can do

`touch /media/sf_sisifo01/restapi1/TWEET_LOAD_3205.log`
and if works. And my guess is that Oracle should be using that same user.

I've tried to give permissions to the shared directory both from the `root` user and the host (although I suspect the host cannot control that - anyway my knowledge of Linux admin is quite limited) - no success.

The permissions for the shared directory are the following:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ ls -l /media/sf_sisifo01 
total 200
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   476 Mar 30 09:08 restapi1
```

and I don't manage to give `r` and `x` permissions for `all users`.
Thanks for reading and for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes in a fresh day you see things differently...

I've added *all* users to group `vboxsf`. Not that I find the solution particularly elegant (I'd accept a better answer if somebody posts it). But it works and I don't quite see the harm on it.

There were two users in the vm beside `oracle`, their ids are: `davfs2`and `dm`. No idea what's their use.